# Geometric description of homomorphism $S_4\longrightarrow S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

$G_R$ := group of rotations of a $3$-dim. cube ($G_R\cong S_4$)

$G_T$ := symmetry group of tetrahedron ($G_T\cong S_4$)

I faintly recall the existence of an argument proving that $G_R$ contains a normal subgroup $N$ of order $4$ (the Klein 4-group in fact, but that's beside the point) by placing the edges of a tetrahedron onto the side diagonals of the cube and then defining a group homomorphism $f$: $G_R\longrightarrow G_T$ with $\left|Im(f)\right|=6$ by giving a geometric description of what $f(\sigma)$ does with the tetrahedron in terms of what $\sigma\in G_R$ does with the cube. (There are algebraic descriptions, of course, but I'm interested in the geometric one.)

On the spot I can only think of several ways where $f$ fails to be a homomorphism. What is the way to do this?

Comment: But isn't the [group of all symmetries of the tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry) isomorphic to $S_{4}$ instead?

Comment: Of course it is, I corrected the typo. Thanks!